# How can I delete a Vertex in Gremlin Server Titan 1.0

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I'm using Titan 1.0 Version and Gremlin Server with REST Api for creating and updating Vertex details.
How can I delete the vertex using vertexId?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use drop property to delete a vertex like :

> g.V(vertexId).drop()

you will find more details about drop property on following link :

[TinkerPop3 Documentation](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/)

Comment: `g.V(vertexId).next().remove()` will also do the trick. If you have the vertex already then simply `v.remove()`. Any of the 3 will serve.

Comment: Please note that `g.V(vertexId).drop()` without iterating the result will only work in Gremlin console that iterates results automatically. In a Java program, to actually trigger the removal, iteration needs to be requested like this: `g.V(vertexId).drop().iterate()`

Comment: Also, if the `Vertex` instance you have is a `ReferenceVertex` (which seems to be the case when you are working via a remote connection), `v.remove()` will not work at all as removal is not supported for `ReferenceVertex`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

```
 g.V().hasId(vertexId).drop()
```

In the hasId method pass the id of the vertex you want to delete